# How to load environment variables from a dotenv file in Flyway?

Tags: flyway

[Flyway supports environment variables in config files](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configfiles#environment-variable-substitution).

Is there a way to make Flyway load these variables from a file, similarly to what [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) and [Node.js with dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) do?

The content of the `.env` file is for example:

```
DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name
```

And `flyway.conf`:

```
flyway.url=${DB_URL}
```

Comment: Hey @Marco. Did you try out any of the approaches I suggested? Any updates? Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty that was useful, thanks. I am waiting a few more days to see if anyone has other ideas before accepting your answer

Comment: Sure np @Marco.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `flyway-maven-plugin`, you have 3 ways currently:

1. Defining flyway properties in POM.xml

eg.

```
  <properties>
    <flyway.url>jdbc:h2:mem:public;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "public";</flyway.url>
    <flyway.user>root</flyway.user>
    <flyway.password></flyway.password>
  </properties>
```

2. Defining your flyway properties in some `.env` or a `.conf` file.

```
mvn -Dflyway.configFiles=src/main/resources/some-env-file.env flyway:migrate
```

Contents of `some-env-file.env`:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:public;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "public";
flyway.user=root
flyway.password=
```

3. Injecting the environment variables directly during maven goal execution:

```
 mvn -Dflyway.url="jdbc:h2:mem:public;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS public;" -Dflyway.user=root -Dflyway.password=root flyway:migrate
```

But if you want to load properties from some file using `properties-maven-plugin`  and make them available as enviroment variables, to be used by your `flyway-maven-plugin` , then **unfortunately that is not working**.

Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2876) tracking this.